# How save the result from task in database using django_celery_results?

Tags: django, celery, django-celery

I am beginner with Celery, and i need to save the result of the task in the database

here is tasks.py:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals

from celery import shared_task
import hashlib
from project.celery import app
from .models import Puzzle

@shared_task(ignore_result=False)
def solve_puzzle(data, level):
    # try to find a nounce value that makes the SHA-1 hash of the data and the nounce start with a certain number of zeros
    solution = ""
    nounce = 0
    while not solution.startswith("".join(["0" for _ in range(level)])):
        solution = hashlib.sha1(f"{data}{(nounce)}".encode()).hexdigest()
        nounce += 1
    return nounce, solution
```

the celery.py:

```
import os

from celery import Celery

# Set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'project.settings')

app = Celery('project', broker='redis://localhost', backend='db+sqlite:///results.sqlite')

# Using a string here means the worker doesn't have to serialize
# the configuration object to child processes.
# - namespace='CELERY' means all celery-related configuration keys
#   should have a `CELERY_` prefix.
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
app.conf.retry = 360
app.conf.timeout = 300

# Load task modules from all registered Django apps.
app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

settings.py:
 `CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'django-db'`

I run celery using the command:
`celery -A project worker -l INFO`
then got :

```
`[2023-09-30 19:29:13,461: INFO/MainProcess] Task puzzle.tasks.solve_puzzle[e1960235-801d-4bc4-8f5d-e7fb923830ba] received
[2023-09-30 19:29:15,909: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-21] child process 624 calling self.run()
[2023-09-30 19:29:18,345: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-22] child process 9428 calling self.run()`
```

but the Task results doesn't have the result of the rask.

Comment: Your function does not return anything?

Comment: return nounce, solution

Comment: Can you share the code where you are accessing celery task result?